# How to check whether a given language is decidable when the definition contains some predetermined machine

Tags: turing-machines, automata

> Let $L = \{\langle M, W \rangle \mid M $ is a Turing machine, w is a string and some Turing Machine $M_1$ exists such that w does not belong to $L(M) \cap L(M_1)\}$

I am unsure of how to deal with the TM $M_1$. One idea I had was to let $L(M_1) = \phi$ such that $L(M) \cap \phi = \phi$. So when we simulate $w$ on $M$ we can immediately accept without reading any input at all since all languages belong to the complement of $\phi$.

Hence from this we can prove that $L$ is decidable since we are always accepting the string regardless of what we input. However I am concerened about the correctness and validity of such a proof. Can someone explain whether the proof is correct if what changes I would need to make to make it make sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The machine $M_1$ is not a predetermined machine, but we rather find that $M_1$ is within the scope of an existential quantor. As you have observed, for all $w$ and $M$ there is some $M_1$ such that $w \notin L(M) \cap L(M_1)$, namely some $M_1$ which always answers "no".

Thus, we can simplify the definition of $L$ to:

$$L = \{\langle M,w\rangle \mid M \text{ is a Turing machine } \wedge w \in \Sigma^*\}$$

As long as our coding of Turing machines is sensible, this shows that $L$ is decidable.

A criticism on your writeup: We never run $M$ on $w$, because there is no point in doing so.